# Existence of a solution to $f(x) = \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

Let $X = (0,1)\times (0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure, and $k\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable non-negative function such that
$$ \int_0^1 k(x,y) dy = 1$$
for every $x \in (0,1)$.

My question is:

> What (more) should we assume on $k$ to guarantee that there exists a unique (up to equivalence class) function $f \in L^1(0,1)$ such that
>   $$f(x) = \int_0^1 k(y,x) f(y) dy$$
>   for every $x \in (0,1)$ and $\| f \|_{L^1(0,1)} = 1$.

Additionally, if we can prove that such unique $f$ exists, when it is strictly positive a.e.?

I would be grateful for any reference.

---

**Edit:** I realized that it makes no sense to ask for a unique solution, since if there is one solution, then all its scalar multiple are also solutions. Hence, I added the requirement that $f \in L^1(0,1)$ and $\| f \|_{L^1(0,1)} = 1$.

Comment: I'm a bit preoccupied so I can't give much thought to this, but if I recall correctly, this falls in the purview of Fredholm theory. There are some nice results that you might be able to use.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Thanks. I do not see how to apply Fredholm theory yet, but it may be a good staring point.

Comment: A family of examples comes from those functions $ k $ that are independent of the first variable; i.e. when there exists $ g : ( 0 , 1 ) \to \mathbb R $ with $ k ( x , y ) = g ( y ) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $ (so we must have $ \int _ 0 ^ 1 g ( y ) \ \mathrm d y = 1 $). In those cases, the only eigenfunctions of the integral operator are those of the form $ f ( x ) = a g ( x ) $ for some constant $ a \in \mathbb R $, and the requirement of existence of a positive eigenfunction becomes positiveness of $ g $.

Comment: I think the paper "[The Existence of Eigenvalues for Integral Operators](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1964-113-01/S0002-9947-1964-0169090-0/S0002-9947-1964-0169090-0.pdf)" by Karlin contains what you're looking for. See Theorem 2 and the citations appearing after it, for example.

Answer (score 3):

May I change the order of $x$ and $y$ to more natural $K(x,y)=k(y,x)$. So we have 
$$
K(x,y)\ge 0,\quad \int_0^1 K(x,y)\,dx=1.
$$
First some examples.

**Example 1:** Let $K(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$. Not a function, but it is easy to see what happens here. We have for all continuous $f$
$$
\int_0^1K(x,y)f(y)\,dy=f(x).
$$
No uniqueness.

**Example 2:** Let's modify the example and take a function now
$$
K(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
2,\quad \text{if}\ (x,y)\in(0,\frac12)^2,\\
2,\quad \text{if}\ (x,y)\in(\frac12,1)^2,\\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is straightforward to see that the function
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
C_1,\quad \text{if}\ x\in(0,\frac12),\\
C_2,\quad \text{if}\ x\in(\frac12,1)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
satisfies the equation
$$
f(x)=\int_0^1K(x,y)f(y)\,dy
$$
for all constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. Clearly, no uniqueness again. Take e.g. $C_1=2$, $C_2=0$ and then $C_1=0$, $C_2=2$ to get two non-negative nomalized solutions.

**Example 3:** Take now the finite dimensional analogue of the problem: a non-negative square matrix $A$ with the condition
$$
e^TA=e^T,\qquad e^T=\left[\matrix{1 &1&\ldots&1}\right]
$$
and look for the solution to $f=Af$ (existence, uniqueness etc). Since the matrix is non-negative we are in the field of [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) that tells us that there exists an eigenvalue $\rho(A)$ and a non-negative eigenvector $f$ such that $\rho(A) f=Af$. Pre-multiplying by $e^T$ we get
$$
\rho(A)e^Tf=e^TAf=e^Tf\ne 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad \rho(A)=1.
$$
So we have existence of a non-negative solution. Uniqueness is not granted by non-negativity of $A$, we need $A$ to be *irreducible*, then we have the strictly positive vector $f$ and uniqueness.

**Conclusion:** There is a generalization of Perron-Frobenius theorem which is called [Krein-Rutman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Rutman_theorem) (see also [here](ftp://ftp.ma.utexas.edu/pub/papers/llave/.grad/5999_chap1-1.pdf)) that says approximately the same for a positive *compact* operator. So you need more conditions on your kernel function to get compactness and irreducibility of the integral operator.

Comment: Great! Many thanks. I was aware of such examples and that is why I asked about what *conditions* should $k$ satisfy for the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: @xen While this is an old post and everything, I'm inclined to note that situations like this are exactly why it is expected of the poster of the question to provide context. If you knew all this, it would have been better to include it in the post so that those who were going to answer could put their effort in the part that you were actually concerned with.